# Problems regarding KCL & KVL

Tags: current-source, kirchhoffs-laws, voltage-source

**Question:**
Below figure represents an approximate equivalent circuit of a field effect transistor amplifier. Using KCL find the output voltage \$v_2\$ in terms of input voltage \$v_1\$.
[image]

**My try:**
I redrew the circuit as:
[image]

Here, \$i_1=\frac{v_1}{r+r_g}\$, \$i_2=\frac{v_2}{r_d}\$, \$i_3=\frac{v_2}{r_l}\$ and \$v_g=\frac{v_1r_g}{r+r_g}\$.
I applied the KCL at node x,
$$i_1+\alpha v_g+i_2+i_3=0\\
\implies \frac{v_1}{r+r_g}+\frac{\alpha v_1r_g}{r+r_g}+\frac{v_2}{r_d}+\frac{v_2}{r_l}=0\\
\implies \frac{v_1}{r+r_g}(1+\alpha r_g)=-v_2\left(\frac1r_d+\frac1r_l\right)\\
\implies \frac{v_1}{r+r_g}(1+\alpha r_g)=-v_2\frac{r_l+r_d}{r_lr_d}\\
\implies v_2=-\frac{v_1r_lr_d}{(r+r_g)(r_l+r_d)}(1+\alpha r_g)$$
But, in my book the answer is:
$$v_2=-\frac{\alpha r_gv_1r_dr_l}{(r_g+r)(r_d+r_l)}$$
Please check my mistake.

Comment: Hint: all current flows in loops. Where is the return for \$ i_1 \$? Does that help you give an exact value for \$ i_1 \$?

Comment: You can solve this problem by considering the two "parts" of the circuit as a voltage divider and a current divider, respectively.

Comment: This circuit is not a good approximation for a MOSFET.MOSFET V/I diagram is a curve it is not linear.

Comment: @Transistor I got it. Thank you very much